# can I drive 100 or so LRAs with WS2811 controlling DRV2603?

Tags: arduino, pwm, led-strip, vibration, vibration-motor

I would like to make a suit with 100 or more individually controllable Linear Resonant Actuators. Texas Instruments makes this http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv2603.pdf which take a PWM as an input to control the vibration intensity. I'm wondering if instead of lighting LEDs with http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2811.pdf could one of these be wired to 3 DRV2603s?

Looking at the data sheets, it seems the DRV2603 accepts a PWM between 10 and 250 khz. I'm not clear on what the WS2811 outputs. The datasheet reads 400 or 800 khz but that is operation freq. Here www.world-semi.com/en/Driver/Lighting_LED_driver_chip/WS2811/ I see 2.5khz scanning freq, so I'll assume that.

The other hurdle I see is digital input high current max of 3uA on the DRV2603 while the WS2811 has a constant current output of 18.5mA. I assume that would fry the DRV2603.

Are these totally incompatible? How would the DRV2603 treat a PWM of 2.5 khz? Would I get 25 levels of intensity instead of 255?

How does constant current work? Is there a way to make this chip output less current? Could I maybe drive an led and then throw a resistor in parallel with the LED to drive the LRA as a side-effect of lighting the LED? I've seen Running Man and I know that would look good at least.

I'm certainly open to more proper solutions but this seems appealing for the price of these components. I am planning on using an Arduino with adafruit's neopixel library if this approach proves feasible. The arduino will be used to communicate with a computer over USB serial, so if an alternate solution involves some kind of USB to lots of PWM outputs, that would be great too.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Input currents are usually requirements, not limits.

Comment: The ws2811 has open collector outputs.  You can convert them by using a inverter or a npn transistor. The ws2811 also has selectable current control I believe

Comment: Do you want to individually control the strength of each LRA, or just be able to turn it on and off?

Comment: @bigjosh I want to individually control the strength.

Comment: I do not think using WS2811s is a good solution for this project. You could instead use something like an ATTINY25 to control the LRAs. Each ATTINY could control several LRAs and also have a connection link back to  a central controller. While using a DRV2603 for each LRA may make controlling them easier, I do not think it is necessary and adds to space and cost requirements. Instead, I think you could drive the LRAs from the ATTINYs using some power transistors. LMK if you are still actively working on this project and more details.

Comment: @bigjosh issues because they're so small? It seems simple enough to mass produce 100 breakout boards which are still going to be tiny enough to sew into fabric. If the WS2811 is a viable option, I see these boards as clusters of 3 LRA/DRV2603 combos around a WS2811. The wiring going to each cluster is V+, GND, DIN and DOUT which might get messy but not messy enough to keep me from doing it.

Comment: @bigjosh I am still working on it, or will work on it rather. As I understand there is a rather narrow sweet spot of frequency that LRAs are most efficient and the appeal of the DRV is that it adjusts to this sweet spot automagically. Looking at the ATtiny now. 6 I/O pins, so I expect that I'd be programming one of these to output a PWM on each of 5 output pins controlling an LRA according to some input signal which I'll have to devise coming from the central controller. Either that or chain them much like the WS2811 and have each control 4 LRAs?

Comment: I understand what you are thinking and it is an interesting solution, but I think you will have problems trying to get it to work in practice. I can go into details if you like, but you are basically looking to use the WS2811 as a shift register and PWM generator and these are functions that you can do directly with something like an ATTINY with more control so that the output signal is compatible with the DRV2603. It might even be possible to drive the LRA directly from the ATTINY and save 1 chip per LRA.

Comment: The simplest solution might be to connect 4 DRV2603s to each ATTINY, one to each of the ATTINY's dedicated PWM pins. This leaves 2 pins available for a daisy chain-style communication link like the WS2811 use. Software in this case could be very simple. But considering you are going to be making *lots* of these, I'd at least play with driving the LRAs directly from the ATTINYs.

Comment: @bigjosh I'm going to buy a few ATtiny85's and see what I can do. Thanks for pointing me in this direction. Do you have any opinion on how to implement WS2811-like communication with these? I found this post that indicates 4PWMs is not so trivial but at least possible: http://www.technoblogy.com/show?LE0

Comment: A lot depends on how you are going to physically arrange and connect everything since wire management is going to be a primary challenge here. Are you going to build this inside of a rigid form (like the inside of a hard shell suit), or is it going to be a stretchy net that huge the wearer's body?

Comment: As far as communications, just straight serial at 5 volts should work fine for the board-to-board distances you are targeting. The ATTINY25 has built a in UART that make serial easy, but it shares pins with the PWM hardware so you will have to bit bang one or the other. This will not be hard because the problem is so focused and well defined.

Comment: I appreciate all the guidance @bigjosh! The LRAs will be sewn into stretchy fabric that will hug the body. Silicone casts will also be explored. I don't have a single end product in mind. There will be several manifestations. I read up more on the DRV and the DRV2605 actually receives I2c. TI also makes a chip that will route to up to 8 drivers. The chip itself can be assigned 1 of 8 addresses. That's 64 LRAs on 1 I2c bus. I ordered parts and will report back. Also ordered some ATtinies to have around :-)

Comment: I2C direct would save chips, but still requires 2 communication wires per bus. If you really wanted to minimize wiring, I think you could multiplex the communication over the power lines, so there would only be two wires for the whole suit. All depends on the what you want to optimize for...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have found answers to all your questions. You could connect the DRV2603 to a Lithium battery supply. You need to maintain the voltage rating of the datasheet (2.5-5V) rather than connecting to a current source.

When the LRAs are vibrating you will see the DRV2603 will consume around 30-90mA to vibrate the LRA.

For vibrating multiple LRAs, you can hookup say OUT+ of 10LRAs to 10 DRV2603s and connect the rest of OUT-'es to a switch. There is an example of this one in the EVM schematic. I would get a digital switch for that one so that you can communicate with a micro-controller.

You can also post your question on the E2E TI Haptics forum too for an in-depth Haptic questions.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get some good info from the TI Haptics forum!